# Proving number is divisible using congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that $13$ divides $146^6+1$.

> My intuition is to use congruence and find a way to form that into an
> equation in which we can factor out $13$. Using congruence we get $13
>  \equiv 146^6+1$ mod($13$) I am not sure where to go from here however.

Comment: What does $>\equiv$ mean?

Comment: Compue it $\bmod 13$ using the congruence rules in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be proven, because it is actually the case that $13$ does not divide $146^6+1$. Perhaps it is a typo and you meant $146^6-1$?

Using basic modular arithmetic rules:
$$146^6\equiv3^6\equiv(3^3)^2\equiv27^2\equiv1^2\equiv1\pmod{13}$$
So, $146^6+1$ is actually equivalent to $2\pmod{13}$, not $0\pmod{13}$ as we would expect if $13$ divides $146^6+1$. You can even verify this answer by typing in "146^6 + 1 mod 13" in Wolfram Alpha.

Now if the problem were asking about $146^6-1$ instead, then it follows from $146^6\equiv1\pmod{13}$ that $146^6-1\equiv0\pmod{13}$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry, I don't realize this is dupe